# Accessing and modifying thread data problem in c++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have problems to access and modify my multiple thread data. Is there are any proper way to do this?

Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

// Create thread data structure
struct data
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char *c;
};

DWORD WINAPI threadfn(LPVOID lpParam)
{   
    printf("Address of thread data:\n");

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(lpParam); i++)
        printf("%X\n", (int*)lpParam + i);

    // Print out initial values
    printf("\nInitial values:\n");
    printf("a: %d\n", *((int*)lpParam));
    printf("b: %.2f\n", *((float*)lpParam + 1));
    printf("c: %s\n", *((int*)lpParam + 2));

    // Modify thread data values
    *(int*)lpParam = 200;
    *((float*)lpParam + 1) = 25.80;
    *((char*)lpParam + 2) = "Es la una";

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    data thread;

    // Set initial thread data values
    thread.a = 10;                  // Integer data type
    thread.b = 15.60;               // Float data type
    thread.c = "Que hora es?";      // String data type

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadfn, &thread, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    // Print out thread value after modification
    printf("\nAfter thread modifications:\n");
    printf("a: %d\n", thread.a);
    printf("b: %.2f\n", thread.b);
    printf("c: %s\n", thread.c);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my output:

```
Address of thread data:
28FF20
28FF24
28FF28
28FF2C

Initial values:
a: 10
b: 15.60
c: Que hora es?

After thread modifications:
a: 7405768
b: 25.80
c: Que hora es?
```

As you can see, the 'c' value is same. How do i modify string value?

Comment: Side comment. Instead of manually handling the pointer arithmetic, which is easy to get wrong, you should just cast the parameter to the known type in `threadfn`: `data * param = static_cast<data*>(lpParam); /*...*/ param->a = 200; param->b = 25.80;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What on earth are you doing?!  All the casting of lpData is very, very wrong.  If you have to do that much casting to accomplish something, you are probably not doing it the right way.

Anyway, your code should look like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI threadfn(LPVOID lpParam)
{   
    printf("Address of thread data:\n");

    data *lpData = (data *)(lpParam);

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(lpParam); i++)
        printf("%X\n", (int*)lpParam + i);

    // Print out initial values
    printf("\nInitial values:\n");
    printf("a: %d\n", lpData->a);
    printf("b: %.2f\n", lpData->b);
    printf("c: %s\n", lpData->c);

    // Modify thread data values
    lpData->a = 200;
    lpData->b = 25.80;
    lpData->c = "Es la una";

    return 0;
}
```

You should be using `(data *)(lpParam)` because it basically reverses what's happening when you call `CreateThread`.  Personally, think the stupid `P` notation for type names is more of a hinderance than a help because it obscures what's actually happening.  [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) in general has this problem IMHO.

In your `main` function, you have this code:

```
hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadfn, &thread, 0, NULL);
```

The 4th argument to `CreateThread` is a `void *` (aka a `PVOID`).  The type of the expression `&thread` is `data *`.  This means that the `data *` is being implicitly converted to a `void *`.  If you make that conversion explicit, the code looks like this:

```
hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadfn, (void *)(&thread), 0, NULL);
```

So, in order to 'undo' what was done, you need to 'reverse' the cast.  You need to turn the `void *` back into a `data *`, which means than in `threadfn` you need the code `data *lpData = (data *)(lpParam);`.

Additionally, you are courting disaster by setting `c` to point at constant character strings since you didn't declare it as a `const char *`.  I'm surprised the compiler isn't giving you an error.  The disaster happens when you do something like `data.c[0] = 'f';`.  When you do that you will be trying to modify memory that may very well be flagged as read-only and cause your program to crash.  And that's the kindest thing that could happen.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking over this method but keep getting errors.

Comment: @Chicko Bueno - Do you understand why the cast I did (aka `data *lpData = (data *)(lpParam);`) is the right thing to do?

Comment: Could you please explain to me "(data *)(lpParam)" in a human language form. So much appreciated.

Comment: @Chicko Bueno - I added my explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're not accessing your structure members properly from within the spawned thread.  Consider this:

```
*(int*)lpParam = 200;
```

It means convert the lpParam to an int*, then access the integer at that address.  That works fine, but:

```
*((float*)lpParam + 1) = 25.80;
```

Converts lpParam to a float*, then adds sizeof(float*) bytes to it, then dereferences it.  That only works if sizeof(int) happens to be the same as sizeof(float)... which is common enough but not guaranteed.

```
 *((char*)lpParam + 2) = "Es la una";
```

This is a real worry though: this considers lpParam a char*, then adds two BYTES to it, which probably positions it half way into the four bytes used by the integer member of the struct (assuming a 32 bit app), then writes over the single character at that address with a truncated value (the least significant byte/char) from the char pointer to your new string [incorporating correction thanks to Chris's comment].

Instead:

```
data* p = (data*)lpParam;
p->a = ...;
p->b = ...;
p->c = ...;
```

The basic point here is that the thread function takes a void* argument, so you lose the type information.  The first thing you want to do with it when your thread starts running is restore that type information so the compiler can check what you're doing is safe and sensible.

Comment: Your answer makes a great adjunct to my answer.  :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious: yeah - do work well together - you've solved it (and noted the char* issue), and I've explained some more (^_^)

Comment: "then writes over the rest of that int and part of the float member with a char pointer to your new string." -- Nope, that assignment is just to a char, it writes only one byte. In this case the 3rd least significant byte of the int. Note, 740578 == 0x007100B2 == 0x00710000 + 200.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer arithmetic is off.

c is at offset 8 in the struct.

However:

```
 *((char*)lpParam + 2) = "Es la una";
```

You cast lpParam to a char*.  Char's have a size of 1 byte (on Windows at least.)  You add two to the pointer, so you are writing to offset 2 bytes in the struct.

Your other pointer arithmetic happens to work since you cast lpParam to a float*, meaning (float*)lpParam + 1 writes to offset 4 in the struct.

As Omnifarius suggested, just cast lpParam to a pointer to the thread data structure and access the members through that.